# Adjoint operator in the space $C[0, 1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider operator $A \in B(C[0, 1])$, $(Ax)(t) := x(0) + tx(1) + t^2\int_0^1 x(s)ds$, where $x(t) \in C[0, 1]$. I'm trying to find adjoint operator $A^*$.

To find the adjoint operator I am trying to solve the equation $f_y(Ax) = g_z(x)$, where $x \in C[0, 1]$ and $f_y(x) = \int_0^1 x(t)dy(t)$, where $y(t) \in BV_0[0, 1]$, for $dz(t)$. For $t = 0$ irealized, that $z(t)$ should equal to zero, but in other cases, I find it difficult to find the function $z(t)$. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

$BV_0[0, 1]$ is a space of functions of limited variation for which $y(0) = 0$, where $y(t) \in BV_0[0, 1]$

Comment: The operator $A$ is $3$-dimensional. You can find the adjoint separately for every term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $g\in BV_0[0,1]$ let $\varphi_g$ denote the corresponding linear functional. For $x\in C[0,1]$ we have
$$(A^*\varphi_g)(x)=\varphi_g(Ax)=\int\limits_0^1(Ax)(t)\,dg(t)=\int\limits_0^1\left [x(0)+tx(1)+t^2\int\limits_0^1x(s)\,ds\right ]\,dg(t)\\
=m_0(g)x(0)+m_1(g)x(1)+m_2(g)\int\limits_0^1 x(s)\,ds$$
where $m_k(g)=\int\limits_0^1t^k\,dg(t).$ Hence
$$(A^*\varphi_g)(x)=\int\limits_0^1x(t)\,dh(t)$$ where
$$h(t) =m_0(g)u_0(t)+m_1(g)u_1(t)+m_2(g)\, t\quad (*)$$
and $$u_0(t)=\begin{cases} 0 & t=0\\
1 & 0< t\leq 1\end{cases}\qquad u_1(t)=\begin{cases} 0 & 0\leq t<1\\
1 & t=1\end{cases}$$
Thus $A^*\varphi_g=\varphi_h,$ where $h$ is given by $(*)$.

Comment: How did we get that the function $h(t)$ has the form above? And how did we get functions $u_0, u_1$?

Comment: I have re-edited. Should be clearer.

Comment: I don't fully understand why $h$ looks like this: $m_0(g)u_0(t) + m_1(g)u_1(t) + m_2(g)t$

Comment: We have $\int\limits_0^1x(t)\,du_0(t)=x(0),$  $\int\limits_0^1x(t)\,du_1(t)=x(1).$  The integral $\int\limits_0^1x(t)\,dt$ corresponds to the  integration with respect to increments of the function $t.$

Comment: I understand, thank you!